# how to reload dataTable

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatables

I want to empty the table before processing. It's showing error.

> Cannot read property 'aDataSort' of undefined.

i am calling like this: `$('#fulltalktimepdata').dataTable().empty();`

```
 $.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "/recharge_plan/",
  data: {
    'phone_no': phone_no
  },
  dataType: "json",
  success: function(msg1) {
    var fulltalktime_jsonString = msg1.fulltalktime_response_data;
    var fulltalktime_temp_data = JSON.parse(fulltalktime_jsonString);
    var fulltalktime_array_of_arrays = [];
    $.each(fulltalktime_temp_data.data["FTT"], function(i, dataElem) {
      fulltalktime_array_of_arrays.push([dataElem.amount, dataElem.detail, dataElem.validity, dataElem.talktime]);
    });
    console.log(fulltalktime_array_of_arrays);
    $('#fulltalktimepdata').dataTable().empty();
    $('#fulltalktimepdata').DataTable({
      data: fulltalktime_array_of_arrays,
      columns: [{
          title: "AMOUNT"
        },
        {
          title: "DETAIL"
        },
        {
          title: "VALIDITY"
        },
        {
          title: "TALKTIME"
        }
      ]
    });
  }
});
```

> Cannot read property 'aDataSort' of undefined

Comment: You cant reload a datatable like that and you actually cant re-initialize a datatable at all. Check out https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax. You need to set up your datatable to load it's contents from your server via the  `ajax` option rather than trying to manipulate the dom manually after initializing the table

Comment: You will need to destroy the datatable instead of making it empty and it will work.

Comment: i tried with $('#fulltalktimepdata').DataTable().destroy(); also getting same error.